# Find elements position in html with js

Tags: javascript, html, arrays

I want to find html position of elements then save it in an array like this :

```
<h1>an element</h1>
<p>another element</p>
// Start saving here
<div class="element-to-save">text1</div>
<div class="element-to-save">text2</div>
<div class="element-to-save">text3</div>
```

And the array :

```
array[0].innerHTML // return text1 
array[1].innerHTML // return text2
```

I don't want to make id or something like that for the divs because the divs can be deleted by the user.
I have no idea to how I could do that

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `document.getElementsByClassName()` and then convert that to an array. If the DIVs are removed from the DOM they will still be in the array:

```
array = Array.from(document.getElementsByClassName("element-to-save"));
```